# Django Count Aggregation with Filter on Related Field Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Suppose I've got 2 models Coupon and UserRedemption (and of course a user model).  They look like:

```
Coupon(models.Model):
    offer = models.TextField() # not important to this task
    limited_use = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    max_uses = models.IntegerField(default=0)

UserRedemption(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
```

so pretty basic.  There are coupons in my app and each coupon has a list of times it's been redeemed by various users.  Some coupons are "limited use", ie they can only be used a certain number of times by a given user.

My goal: return a list of coupons excluding the coupons which have been used the maximum number of times by the user making the request.

I'm attempting to do this by annotating the coupons with the number of times it's been redeemed by the current user (n_user_redemptions) and filtering the list for coupons where limited_use = False OR max_uses > n_user_redemptions.  Here is my attempted method on the Coupon class:

```
@classmethod
def get_available_user_coupons(cls, user):
    coupon_redemption_count = Count('userredemption', filter=Q(userredemption__user=user))
    return cls.objects.annotate(n_user_redemptions=coupon_redemption_count)
                      .filter(Q(limited_use=False) | Q(max_uses__gt=F('n_user_redemptions')))
```

However, it's not filtering properly for the user passed in from the request.  It always sets n_user_redemptions to the count of all redemptions of that coupon by all users, not just the ones for the given user.  I've tested that it returns coupons correctly if limited_use is set to False and if that coupon has been redeemed less times total (by all users) than the max_uses. And I have confirmed that I am passing in the user correctly.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I've gone through the django aggregation docs pretty extensively and it seems like this should work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Just a further update:

I inspected the generated SQL and notice that the queries are identical whether I set:

```
coupon_redemption_count = Count('userredemption', filter=Q(userredemption__user=user))
```

OR

```
coupon_redemption_count = Count('userredemption')
```

Not sure what the behavior of the filter argument is supposed to be in Count.

The relevant SQL:

```
SELECT "coupon_coupon"."id", "coupon_coupon"."offer", "coupon_coupon"."limited_use", "coupon_coupon"."max_uses", 
   COUNT("userredemption_userredemption"."id") AS "n_user_redemptions" 
FROM "coupon_coupon" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "userredemption_userredemption" 
    ON ("coupon_coupon"."id" = "userredemption_userredemption"."coupon_id")
GROUP BY "coupon_coupon"."id" 
ORDER BY "coupon_coupon"."id" DESC
```

No mention of the user anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do it like so:

```
def return_list_of_coupons(user):
    list_of_coupons = [coupon for coupon in Coupon.objects.all()
                       if UserRedemption.objects.filter(user=user.pk, coupon=coupon.pk).count() < coupon.max_uses]
    return list_of_coupons
```

It's simpler and a bit crude, but it does the job just fine.

Comment: Sure this would get it done but would be terribly inefficient. I need production quality. My first alternative here is to just write the raw sql because this sql isn’t actually terribly complicated. I’m asking why the count aggregate filter isn’t working because I don’t want to be writing and managing raw sql and i don’t get why it isn’t working when I ripped this code almost line for line from the Django docs

Answer (score 1):

So I never got an answer or figured out why the aggregate filter wasn’t working but i did figure out a less pretty workaround using a sub query which at least isn’t raw sql which would present a maintenance nightmare and is not forcing me to evaluate multiple queries. I’d prefer to use the aggregate because that uses joins under the hood rather than a sub query which would be the more efficient approach but this will service for now and I will log with the Django team to see what’s up with the aggregate filter.

Here is the work around:

```
coupon_redemption_count = Count(Subquery(UserRedemption.objects.filter(user=user, coupon=OuterRef(‘pk’)).values_list(‘id’, flat=True)))
```

Then everything else is the same.

Leaving this question open in case anyone finds it and can tell me why the aggregate filter isn’t working.